# Calling ServiceStack with backslash in request data

Tags: servicestack

I am calling a service stack api from VB.NET that I've created - It essentially looks up the default language spoken as you pass the nationality of a person.

```
Dim response As BindingList(Of
Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguageResponse)

Dim client As New JsonServiceClient(BASEURI)
    response = client.[Get](New Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguage() With {.NationalityCode = strNationality})
```

strNationality is a code from a database called "ME/Kuw" (Kuwaiti which would return Arabic"

Any code that does not have a "/" or a "\" in it returns correctly so I know the service and calls work however if I use a code ie . "ME/Kuw" I get a service not found - its sort of interpreting the / as a route,
I've tried making the string URLencoded , but its the same issue.

This is my service and response code - which works fine as long as no "/" is in the .NationalityCode.

```
 <Route("/SystemFunctions/DefaultLanguage/{NationalityCode}", "GET")>
 Public Class Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguage
     Implements IReturn(Of BindingList(Of ymphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguageResponse))

Private mvarNationalityCode As String
     Public Property NationalityCode() As String
         Get

             NationalityCode = mvarNationalityCode

         End Get
         Set(ByVal Value As String)

             mvarNationalityCode = Value

         End Set
     End Property 
End Class


 Public Class Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguageResponse
     Private mvarDefaultLanguage As String

     Public Property DefaultLanguage() As String
         Get

             DefaultLanguage = mvarDefaultLanguage

         End Get
         Set(ByVal Value As String)

             mvarDefaultLanguage = Value

         End Set
     End Property 
End Class
```

and my class that gets the data.

```
public Class Symphony_SystemFunctionsService
    Inherits Service Public Function [get](request As Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguage) As Object

        Using dbcontext As New EntitiesModel1

            Dim sqlQueryString As String = "proc_s_GetDefaultLanguage '" & request.NationalityCode & "'"
            Dim response As IEnumerable(Of Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguageResponse) =
 dbcontext.ExecuteQuery(Of
 Symphony_SystemFunctionsDefaultLanguageResponse)(sqlQueryString)

            Return response

        End Using

    End Function 
End Class
```

Any suggestions how I might call this and allow the passing of "/" in that data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a [wildcard path](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Routing#wildcard-paths) in your Route attribute:

```
'        Added an asterisk here------------------------> v
<Route("/SystemFunctions/DefaultLanguage/{NationalityCode*}", "GET")>
```

This should allow your `NationalityCode` property to get values with slashes.